# Show scheduled posts in loop (but don't link to them)?

Tags: loop, scheduled-posts

Is there a way to show scheduled posts in the regular loop but have them not link? I'd like to show that they're coming soon.

This code makes them visible, but you can click into the post, which I don't want.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $wp_query ) {
global $wp_post_statuses;

if (
    ! empty( $wp_post_statuses['future'] ) &&
    ! is_admin() &&
    $wp_query->is_main_query()
   ) {
    $wp_post_statuses['future']->public = true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to show scheduled posts in the regular loop but have them not link? I'd like to show that they're coming soon.

Yes, if you don't want  to link to them, then don't create links for them.

> This code makes them visible, but you can click into the post, which I don't want.

`pre_get_posts` changes what posts a query fetches, it has nothing to do with how those posts are displayed, how they are displayed is entirely the job of the theme templates.

Oddly though, your `pre_get_posts`  filter does not modify the  query object. The  consequence of this is that all following queries will  have future posts, even if they aren't the main query,  as long as they happen after it.

You  would be much better off just modifying the query instead of  changing WP globals e.g.

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $wp_query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }
    $wp_query->set( 'post_status', [ 'publish', 'future' ] );
});
```

So, how do you only link to the published ones? Easy, just check the status and only link if it's publish

```php
if ( get_post_status() == 'publish' ) {
    // show the post in the loop normally
} else {
   // it's a scheduled post, show it differently
}
```

Comment: That conditional is so obvious now — thank you! I used your code for add_action and it _is_ affecting a WP_Query loop (I don't want scheduled posts to show in that loop). Any idea how I can avoid that? @tom

Comment: Without the `pre_get_posts`, you won't have posts that are scheduled but not published, my understanding was that you wanted scheduled posts to show based on your answer, but as headings, not linked headings. Otherwise you're going to have to be a lot more specific about what you actually want and what's going on, as I don't know what loops you have

Comment: Sorry about that. That code makes scheduled posts show in my main loop (and I used the conditional to not have linked headings). That's perfect. 

But I have another loop on the page (a WP_Query loop that shows the latest posts in a slider) where I _don't_ want scheduled posts to show. 

Is there a way to have them show in the main WP loop but not in the WP_Query loop?

Comment: hmmm that pre_get_posts should only affect the main loop, did you remove your original `pre_get_posts` filter?

Comment: You're right: it's only affecting the main loop.